# How to download Packages for Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, package

I just started Android Development yesterday and just finished with my first Activity. On running it, I'm getting errors like

```
 **Error:(4, 37) error: package android.support.design.widget does not exist**
```

As I never post without it, I've already done plenty of searching on this. Basically, what I've understood is that it couldn't find that Widget Package on my PC. So, do I have to download it? If yes, then how?
People on internet had similar problem with Packages and almost every post has different answer to this. Some say change your Gradle File others say Update your Studio (have done it). 
Any kind of explanation or bit of knowledge with the solution would be highly appreciated. I'm a kind of geek who want to get concepts and basics clear. So, it would be great if you include the reason and technicality behind this too with your answer. Thanks. :)

Comment: look at the bottom of this [page](http://android-developers.blogspot.fr/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a design library for Android apps development and as @Dominique pointed have a look at that page and copy paste that `compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'` line in your project gradle file and press the sync button. Your project will sync in a few moments and the design library will be downloaded. Now you can use this library and there won't be any errors.

Comment: EDIT: Got it running! That line is meant to be copied in build.gradle (**Module:app**). Thank you, all! :)

@Dominique I've pasted that line in build.gradle dependencies block and getting this error now: 

`Error:Could not find method compile() for arguments [com.android.support:design:24.2.1] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

Please install the Android Support Repository from the Android SDK Manager.`

Answer (score 1):

No, in Java "package" is not a "library" or a "piece of software" (like it is in some other languages). Package is what classes belong to - you might think of packages as directories containing Java files (it is a simplification, but it works). In Java libraries are packaged into (usually) "jars" (those jars usually contain classes divided into packages), so what you need to download is "jar".

So, first thing you need to check is: what library contains the package, and configure your IDE accordingly. The package in question belongs, I think to the so called android support library, which you can install using the SDK tool.